# Solve Always with Assumptions

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

How can I use the [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) function imposing some assumption on the parameter space of the symbolic variables?

Comment: `SolveAlways[{eqns, assumptions}, variables]`?

Comment: Ddi not work. Dou mean something in the line of: `SolveAlways[{x^2-1==0,Assumptions->x>0},{x}]`?

Comment: @user191919 Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 3):

In your case [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is enough. [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) are not described in the documentation.

```
Solve[x^2 - 1 == 0 && x > 0, x]
```

> $\{\{x\to 1\}\}$

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the documentation, [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) does not solve for the unknowns. Instead, it finds parameter values for which the set of equations is always satisfied (for all values of unknowns), as in the example:

```
SolveAlways[a x + b == 0, x]
```

> `{{a->0,b->0}}`

This tells you that for `a=0` and `b=0` the equation `a x + b == 0` is always satisfied, regardless of the value of `x`.

If you want to solve an equation with some restriction on the variable domain (field in which the unknown lives), then you can supplement the constraint to the `Solve` function using the `&&` operator. For example:

```
Solve[x^3 + 1 == 0, x]
```

> `{{x -> -1}, {x -> (-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> -(-1)^(2/3)}}`

vs

```
Solve[x^3 + 1 == 0 && x \[Element] Reals, x]
```

> `{{x -> -1}}`

Hope this helps.